# How to create an OOK signal in ADS

Tags: simulation, modulation, amplitude-modulation, cadence, ads

I'm trying to make an OOK modulated signal in ADS. I need a random bit generator, and a block to multiply a sinusoidal signal with that random pulse. I did this in Cadence by the 'rand_bit_stream' and 'pvcvsp' blocks. Are there any similar blocks in ADS?

Answer (score 2):

If a pseudo-random bit sequence is acceptable (and normally this would be preferable to a truly random source or a pseudo-random source driven by the system random number generator), there are the [PRBSsrc](http://edadocs.software.keysight.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5919534) and [VtPRBS](http://edadocs.software.keysight.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5919555) devices:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and how to multiply it by it by a sinusoidal to get an OOK signal?

Comment: Look for an AM modulation component.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow did it with a mixer.[image: ook]